# Finding elements who meet a specific condition

Tags: matlab, find

I've a matrix A and I'd like to find elements of first row which have 1 in the second row. i.e. for following matrix

```
 A=
 2     5     6     1
 1     0     0     1
```

I'd like to have output as hits = [2 1] without using loops. and then finds the maximum items in the answer. i.e. (2>1) so my final answer is 2. The response is probably using arrayfun but I've problems and get errors using it. What is the correct syntax?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
out = max(A(1,A(2,:) == 1))
```

**Example:**

```
>> A

A =

 2     5     6     1
 1     0     0     1

>> out

out =

 2
```

**Explanation:** (if you need)

```
%// create a mask of which column you want
mask = A(2,:) == 1   %// by checking all values of 2nd row with 1

%// get only the values of row one, meeting 'the' condition
hits = A(1,mask)  

%// Find the maximum from that
maxHits = max(hits)
```

**For Cell Array** using `cellfun`

```
A = {[2 5 6 1; 1 0 0 1], [2 3 2 5 4; 1 1 3 1 2]}  %// eg input

A = 

[2x4 double]    [2x5 double]

out = cellfun(@(x) max(x(1,x(2,:) == 1)),A)

out =

 2     5
```

Comment: Thanks, Perfect solution. Now, if it in the case of cellarray e.g. `a{1}={ 2     5     6     1;  1     0     0     1} ; a{2}={ 3     2     4     1;  1     0     0     0}`. can we adapt the solution for this case too? (finding values which have corresponding ones and then getting the max element)

Comment: @hamideh sure check the edit.. change the example `A` into your actual values and test it :)

Comment: Thanks, Big Bravo:) Just another twist: if we would like to check first the number of matched occurrence,(2 1 in cell one and 2 3 5 in cell2)  then we could do sth like `out = cellfun(@(x) numel(x(1,x(2,:) == 1)),A)` ?`out = [2 3]` then only if had equal number of occurrence number, again perform the function `final_out= cellfun(@(x) max(x(1,x(2,:) == 1)),A)`, right?

Comment: @hamideh what if they both are not equal? u want to find `maxhits` only if they have equal occurances?

Comment: Yes, in fact i've some data (B) that i want to put in one of the cells(A). For this, i first check the maximum number of hits of B in A (B is a partial subset of A) and then then I assign B to a cell in A which have the maximum number of matched entity. in the case where some cells have equal number of occurrence, then I assign it to the cell which has the hit items with higher average (or max hit if just one hit happens in each cell) and if not equal number of hits happens, i assign the value to the cell with higher number of hits. complex a bit!

Comment: @hamideh then i guess your approach is correct.. to check if they all have equal occurrences take any occurrence as reference and subtract it from all occurrences so that you might get the deviation from the reference value. If all are equal you may not get any deviation.

Comment: thanks for your confirmation..I found that `F=arrayfun(@(x)(find(B(x)==A)),1:numel(B),'UniformOutput',false)` gives the index of all occurrence in an array. but if I want to use it for the case of different cells in A as my described case, does  `F=cellfun(@(x)(find(B(x)==A)),1:numel(B),'UniformOutput',false)` gives the right answer?

Comment: What is `B` and `A` here? Also `cellfun` wont works as `arrayfun`. have you tried it?

Comment: e.g. in your example `A = {[2 5 6 1]; [2 3 2 5 4]}, B=[5 6 7]` ; then because hits in A{1} are larger than A{2} [2 1] then I choose `A{1}` as the winning cell. I try to find a way to do it with cellfun if possible and report the result..